# is_page() is not working in wordpress even when adding wp_reset_query()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use the is_page function in wordpress and it's not working.
I read here that `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` should solve the problem, but it didn't help. Here is the code:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php if (is_page(379) ): ?>

  <!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any idea/suggestions on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

None of the other solutions worked for me. What did work was to use the `wp` hook.

```
add_action('wp', 'page_check');
function page_check() {
    if (is_page('my-page-slug')) {
      // code to run on this page
    }
}
```

Comment: Hooking into the 'wp' action is a good work around. I didn't want conversion tracking code anywhere other than functions.php for maintainability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php if (get_the_ID()==379): ?>
  <!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me

```
    <?php if(is_page(379)): ?>
    <?php echo 'x'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and it's because I was using query_posts somewhere on the page.

The way I tested it was to echo the $post->ID at the very top of the template file and it gave me the correct ID.

when I echoed it at the bottom (after my query_posts), it was not getting the correct ID.

So you might want to test by doing this and changing any query_posts you have to use WP_Query instead: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query